# Pandas on PyPy 3.5 significantly slower than Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pypy

i have a python web service written using aiohttp and pandas to perform some basic pandas operations. I tried running it with pypy 3.5-9.0 docker (https://hub.docker.com/_/pypy/) and the performance is very slow compare to when i run with python 3.6 docker image Attached are the screenshots of where the time is spent at each function in the call stack and seems like everything is slow.....any clues?

[image: With CPython]
[image: With PyPy]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crossing the python - C boundary is slower in PyPy. Any refactoring of your code to cross that gap less frequently should greatly improve the overall speed. You could contact #pypy on IRC and maybe we could help you analyse what is going on.

There are also some improvements in the PyPy development pipeline, real-world use cases often provide a valuable data point for figuring out what direction future developments should take.

Comment: Thanks @mattip I will reach out on IRC. The above screenshots is a real use case currently deployed in prod (w/o pypy). I can comeup with a slim down version of this use-case that can help troubleshoot the slowness